# Axis webservice returning byte array

Tags: web-services, apache-axis

I wrote a java web service that returns byte array generated from a file.

```
public byte[] callByte(){
   // code that return byte array
}
```

In my client I try to read that byte array as

```
CallStub stub = new CallStub();
byte[] b = stub.callByte();
```

where `CallStub` is the axis client stub. It is saying `type mismatch: cannot convert from CallStub.CallByteResponse to byte[]`
so I understood that the byte is returned in the form of `CallByteResponse` object.

But I want that to be converted into a byte array.
Can you please tell me how to do that.

Answer (score 0):

If you would check the definition of the `CallByteResponse` object, you should find a getter function which returns the byte array that you're looking for.